# Dia crashing with Mac OS 10.11.6

Tags: macos, dia

**Issue:** Since "upgrading" to El Capitan, Dia won't open (icon briefly appears then vanishes).

***Error message*** (when opening via commandline):

```
(process:45300): Gdk-WARNING **: locale not supported by C library

(process:45300): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.

(dia-bin:45300): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.xxxxxxx/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
```

Followed instruction on this bug report: https://sourceforge.net/p/dia-installer/support-requests/105/ without success:

***Error message following code change suggested in bug report:***

```
(process:44516): Gdk-WARNING **: locale not supported by C library

(process:44516): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.

(dia-bin:44516): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

**Relevant Version Information:**

- Dia version 0.97.2 (freshly downloaded from http://dia-installer.de/download/macosx.html)
- XQuartz 2.7.11
- Mac OS 10.11.6

> Has anyone managed to get Dia working with El Capitan?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In case this helps anyone else, a fresh install of XQuartz (https://www.xquartz.org) resolved the issue.

**Note**: still needed the `export DISPLAY=:0` addition at line 39 in the source code.